# How to give link or path to tree submenu to redirecting other component?

Tags: html, angular, path

I want to give routerlink or path or any action to the tree submenu, But I failed, I don't know how to do it please, someone helps me to find out a solution for this,

Here is the .ts file code

```
  public treeData: Object[] = [
{
    nodeId: '1', nodeText: 'DashBoard'
},
{
    nodeId: '2', nodeText: 'Trip Management',
    nodeChild: [
        { nodeId: '21', nodeText: 'Location' },
        { nodeId: '22', nodeText: 'Routes' },
        { nodeId: '23', nodeText: 'Ticket Price' }
    ]
},
{
    nodeId: '3', nodeText: 'Booking',
    nodeChild: [
        { nodeId: '31', nodeText: 'Add Booking' },
        { nodeId: '32', nodeText: 'List' }
    ]
},
{
    nodeId: '4', nodeText: 'Users',
},
{
  nodeId: '5', nodeText: 'Reports',
  nodeChild: [
      { nodeId: '51', nodeText: 'User' },
      { nodeId: '52', nodeText: 'Booking' }
  ]
},
{
  nodeId: '6', nodeText: 'settings',
  nodeChild: [
      { nodeId: '61', nodeText: 'General Setting' },
      { nodeId: '62', nodeText: 'Pages' },
      { nodeId: '63', nodeText: 'Email Formate' },
  ]
},
];

 public treeFields: Object = {
dataSource: this.treeData,
id: 'nodeId',
text: 'nodeText',
Link:'routerLink',
child: 'nodeChild',

};
```

.html file is,

```
            <ejs-treeview id="myTree" [fields]="treeFields" 
            (click)="event($event)"></ejs-treeview >
```

Comment: just add 1 more field in your object like `path:'your file path '`  and defined router and html file set `[routerlink]="path" `

Comment: it's not working for me